# Firebase - Switching from Direct Channel API to FCM HTTP v1 API in Cordova

Tags: firebase, cordova, firebase-cloud-messaging, cordova-plugins

I recently received an email from firebase explaining "Firebase Messaging iOS SDK version 7.0 will be a breaking change where the SDK will no longer support iOS Direct Channel API.".

Essentially they explained that the messaging method needs to be switched from the iOS Direct Channel API to FCM HTTP v1 API.

The app that uses the direct channel API uses cordova and the firebase integration uses [firebasex](https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-plugin-firebasex)

My question is whether compiling the plugin using the method below (taken from [readme](https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-plugin-firebasex)) will result in the new API being used or whether it is more involved than that and further steps need to be taken.

```
IOS_SHOULD_ESTABLISH_DIRECT_CHANNEL - If true Firebase Messaging will automatically establish a socket-based, direct channel to the FCM server.
e.g. --variable IOS_SHOULD_ESTABLISH_DIRECT_CHANNEL=true
Defaults to false if not specified.
See shouldEstablishDirectChannel
Note: Firebase Messaging iOS SDK version 7.0 will be a breaking change where the SDK will no longer support iOS Direct Channel API.
```

Any help is greatly appreciated and please just let me know if more info is needed.